# How to get the Name, email id and telephone number from a business cards in iPhone programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, tesseract

I know how to extract text from images using Tesseract, can any one tell me how to extract the name , telephone number and email from a business cards(Image File by scanning)?

Comment: May be you need to modify the tesseract to use for your purpose.

Comment: @amrit_neo I really dont know how to do this. Can you tell me how to do or do you have any sample. I am really tired of trying this.

Comment: You can use Regular expression to extract emailid,phone number, etc: from the text generated using any OCR tool.

Answer (score 3):

Tesseract Optical Character Recognition (OCR) 
http://maniacdev.com/2011/08/example-tesseract-optical-character-recognition-ocr-demo-with-source/

reads text from image. Once you have the text you can write your own method which will take the text and return the desired result.

```
void detectCharacters(String text){
/**
if you want to detect email search for keyword "Email","email","e-mail",
 "mail-id", etc and read the characters till next empty space or new line is found.
use same thing for name, phonenumber.
**/

}
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try it and say.

Comment: @surendher : Any success met?

Comment: Did you get the solution @surendher ?

Answer (score 2):

I used Camcard and it is good. They are  taking more time to approve SDK request, but its easy to use and straight forward.

try - http://dev.camcard.com

Comment: I am trying to implement cam card code but didn't find CamCardOpenAPIFramework.framework.zip file. Kinldy tell me where it is place on site.

Comment: Firstly, you have to request the license (for example a trial), in order to get the link to the library, also, you would receive the API code.

Comment: Is it paid ? if paid then what are the charge ??

Comment: No sure about the price. You need to request Camcard to know their price model.

Comment: Its too expensive and my request got approved 3 months later.

Comment: I just checked it and the pricing is around 12500 USD for iOS App, + 2250 USD Maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

Use NSDataDetector_Class to find email, phone number , Link, timeZone, Date, Address, Duration etc in a given string.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/)

[Sample Codes](http://nshipster.com/nsdatadetector/)

Answer (score 0):

I have used NSDataDetector for phone number and link. Its working fine. Address detection is not working.